# import library panel for grafana

Tags: grafana, dashboard

I currently am using Grafana in kubernetes. I have some dashboards that are referring to library panels . I can upload dashboard by creating a configmap and referring to that in volume of Grafana pod as show below... How can I get the library panels imported in similar fashion ? Also I don't see a way to export dashboard panel json content. Any help is appreciated.

```
 - mountPath: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
        name: grafana-dashboard
volumes:
  - name: grafana-dashboard
       configMap:
            name: grafana-dashboard
```

```
metadata:
    name: grafana-dashboard
    namespace: monitoring
data:
     default:
          {{ .Files.Get “files/dashboard.json”  | base64enc}}
```

Thank you.